# Stripping specific HTML tags in PHP

Tags: php, strip-tags

I searched a lot about striping HTML tags from some particular database content(field). I got this code somewhere. It works fine. However it is for stripping all HTML tags except those tags that are specified.

But I want to strip tags which I specify and leave other tags as they are. How can I do so?

The code that I found for striping all tags except the provided ones is this:

```
<?php 
   echo strip_tags(nl2br($content), "<img><b><br><p><a>"); 
?>
```

Comment: http://htmlpurifier.org/comparison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strip_tags has also a second parameter where you can set all the tags you do not want to be removed.

That way it will only remove everything you don't want to keep.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php